# Нахождение площади четырехугольников по координатам

Tags: c, координаты

На плоскости задано n точек с координатами x[n], y[n]. Нужно найти четверки точек, составляющие четырехугольник наибольшей площади.

Я написал такой код, который проверяет все возможные комбинации точек, считает площадь по [формуле Гаусса](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A4%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D1%83%D0%BB%D0%B0_%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%89%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B8_%D0%93%D0%B0%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B0) и находит максимальную площадь. Естественно, точек должно быть не меньше 4.

```
for (i = 0; i < n - 3; i++)
            for (j = 1; j < n - 2; j++)
                for (k = 2; k < n - 1; k++)
                    for (l = 3; l < n; l++)
                    {
                        s = fabs(((x[i] * y[j] - y[i] * x[j]) + (x[j] * y[k] - y[j] * x[k]) + (x[k] * y[l] - y[k] * x[l]) + (x[l] * y[i] - y[l] * x[i])) / 2.0);
                        if (s > max) max = s;
                    }
```

И всё бы хорошо, но площадь упорно равна нулю. Подскажите, что я делаю не так. Может проблема в последовательности ввода координат точек? Есть ли другой способ вычисления площади по координатам?

Comment: Модет, проще считать площадь четырехугольника как 2 площади треугольников по формуле Герона, например, или там с синусом?

Comment: @Harry а если треугольники перекрывают друг друга? Да и как определить, входят ли два треугольника в один четырехугольник?

Comment: Ну если у вас четырехугольник ABCD, то берем ABC и ACD. Правда, если четырехугольник не выпуклый, то нужно учитывать знак...

Comment: @Harry: Это не проще, а намного сложнее, ибо четырехугольник может быть невыпуклым. Городит огородж, когда есть нормальная формула для общего случая смысла нет.

Comment: Почему у вас площадь всегда равна нулю отсюда не видно. Может у вас все точки лежат на одной прямой? Также ваши циклы могут брать одну и ту же точку несколько раз, т.е. строить "четырехугольник", который выродился в треугольник. По условию так можно?

Comment: @AnT одну точку несколько раз брать нельзя. Я ввожу координаты 1 1, 3 3, 1 3, 3 1.

Comment: @Watchman: Ну так! При таком входе ваши циклы попробуют один-единственный вариант: `(i = 0, j = 1, k = 2, l = 3)`. При таком порядке вершин вы получаете "бантик" с самопересечением, площадь которого действительно равна `0`. Формула площади отработала совершенно правильно. Как я написал в своем ответе ниже, проблема в ваших пределах в циклах - это какая-то бессмыслица.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Площадь по данным четырем точкам у вас вычисляется правильно.

Если уж вы взялись решать задачу полным перебором, то вам нужно перебирать все возможные комбинации из четырех различных точек во всех относительных порядках. То есть в самом "брутальном" варианте циклы должны выглядеть примерно так

```
for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
  for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
    if (j != i)
      for (k = 0; k < n; k++)
        if (k != i && k != j)
          for (l = 0; l < n; l++)
            if (l != i && l != j && l != k)
              /* Проверяем площадь */;
```

У вас же наблюдается какое-то странное неоправданное исключение некоторых вариантов, но при этом нет никакой защиты от того, что одна и та же точка может быть взята несколько раз. Например, в вашем наборе `( i, j, k, l )` точка `0` может быть только первой, а точка `n-1` - только последней. То есть вариант `( 0, j, n-1, l )` вы никогда не рассмотрите. На каком основании вы исключили такие четырехугольники из рассмотрения?

Из этого перебора, в целях оптимизации, имеет смысл исключить циклические сдвиги одного и того же набора, ибо они описывают один и тот же многоугольник. По той же причине также имеет смысл исключить зеркальные обращения одного и того же набора. Но не более того.

Для исключения из рассмотрения циклических сдвигов достаточно обеспечить, чтобы каждый рассматриваемый набор начинался со своего минимального элемента. Для исключения из рассмотрения зеркальных отражений достаточно обеспечить, чтобы в перестановке `(j, k, l)` содержалось не более одной инверсии

```
for (i = 0; i < n - 3; i++)
  for (j = i + 1; j < n; j++)
    for (k = i + 1; k < n; k++)
      if (k != j)
        for (l = i + 1; l < n; l++)
          if (l != j && l != k)
            if ((j > k) + (k > l) + (j > l) <= 1)
              /* Проверяем площадь */;
```

Например, на наборе из 5 точек такой перебор проверит только 15 вариантов, в то время как полный перебор проверит 5! = 120 вариантов. На наборе из 6 точек - 45 вместо 720.

---

Однако эта задача имеет и эффективное решение. Оно начинается из построения выпуклой оболочки для вашего набора точек.

Если выпуклая оболочка имеет четыре или более вершин, то точки, не лежащие на выпуклой оболочке исключаются из дальнейшего рассмотрения. А дальше [несложный "поворотный" алгоритм](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38436969/how-to-get-max-area-of-k-gon) найдет четырехугольник максимальной площади без полного перебора.

Если же выпуклая оболочка является треугольником, то надо лишь найти дополнительную внутреннюю точку, "выкусывающую" минимальную площадь из этого треугольника.

Comment: Почему точки, не лежащие на выпуклой оболочке, исключаются из перебора?

Comment: а если именно выпуклый четырехугольник, то опять же, почему точки нужно брать только из аутлайна с максимальной внутренней площадью?

Comment: @Alexander Zonov: Да, в общем случае это неверное утверждение. Исключать внутренние точки можно только в том случае, когда выпуклая оболочка имеет не менее 4-х вершин.

Comment: Мне вообще-то тоже так интуитивно кажется. Можно попробовать брутфорсом поискать несоответствия.

Comment: @Alexander Zonov: Ну этот-то факт легко доказывается. Более того, как я сказал выше, если выпуклая оболочка имеет не менее 4 точек, то максимальный четырехугольник будет заведомо выпуклым и будет лежать на оболочке. Только если выпуклая оболочка треугольна, нам надо будет рассматривать невыпуклые четырехугольники.

Comment: Очевидно, что если выпуклая оболочка - четырехугольник, то этот четырехугольник и есть искомый четырехугольник. Больше него по площади ничего построить не выйдет.

Comment: Почему, если выпуклая оболочка имеет не менее 4 точек, то максимальный четырехугольник будет заведомо лежать на оболочке?

Comment: @Alexander Zonov: Хм... Действительно, все не так тривиально... Надо подумать.

Comment: @Alexander Zonov: Вот в этой статье https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0166218X86900296 доказывается, что при `k <= l <= 3` (где `k` - число вершин многоугольника, `l` - число вершин выпуклой оболочки) максимальный по площади k-угольник выпукл и его вершины являются вершинами выпуклой оболочки.